# Need simple idea for a simple android app

Tags: java, android, programming-languages

I am a junior software developer working mostly in c#.

I am being tested at work by my boss for a new role as an android sdk developer. I passed the first interview and now he wants me to write a small application which boasts certain simple features such as communication via GPRS service and handling data (i guess he means use a sqlite table to store some input).

Anyone got any simple ideas you can throw at me to give me a good starting point.

Any ideas are welcome,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple one would be something like an RSS reader - data connection to read a feed, database to store at the very least the feed URLs and (if you get time), also previously DL'd feed items to save data re-use.

If you don't get time to implement everything, be sure to note in code/feedback what additional features you believe are required.

Answer (score 3):

Something like an RSS ready would be a good idea, you could store site preferences locally and check for new data asynchronously. Both are good topics to learn in terms of mobile development.

Comment: LMAO 4 seconds apart with the same idea :D

Comment: I always find something like an RSS reader a good idea, its a simple concept that you can really balls up. Best sort of idea IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Does your company have any sort of webservice API that you could build an app against?  You could both show that you can do a simple app based off of the API and already write something benefical in one swoop.  Or if there isn't a webservice API available, perhaps you could write a small one to show off some potential features you could create for the company for Android devices?

Another idea: An app that has been done again and again is a Twitter app.  Make it really simple, just show the recent timeline, cache the results into a database, check for updates, etc.

Comment: It's a nice idea - I'm in the process of writing something similar in my spare time but I've found that webservices on Android can be a pain unless you control the WS too - It's pretty limited as to what it can talk to without some serious coding (at least if you want it to be robust). That said, if brux has access to an appropriate WS, this is a really nice idea :)

Comment: ok im liking the sound of this twitter app. would i be sending http post commands over tcpip?

Comment: @brux you can probably avoid reinventing the wheel, use a library someone else has made: http://code.google.com/p/java-twitter/